# VSTS - Compile aspx pages on build

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, msbuild, continuous-integration, azure-devops

I have a task on a Visual Studio Team Services configured as follows:

[image]

The solution contains an ASP.NET Web Forms application. The task compiles the solution but unfortunately compilation errors on .aspx files are ignored. Is there any way to check for errors on .aspx pages on build?

Comment: Do you have a Web Site or a Web Application? (Web Applications have Code Behind files)

Comment: Web application - there are Code Behind files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TL;DR Just set the MSBuild property `PrecompileBeforePublish` to 'true'

Long version:
The preferred option is to create a web package (a .zip file), that you could then feed to VSTS Build/Release tasks that would deploy it on [Azure App Service](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/tree/master/Tasks/AzureRmWebAppDeployment) or [IIS](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscs-rm.iiswebapp).

In order to create a web package trigger the [Web Publishing Pipeline](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd394698(v=vs.110).aspx) during build by passing these additional arguments to MSBuild (on the Visual Studio Build task):

```
 /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package
 /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true  /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true    
 /p:PackageLocation="$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)\\"    
 /p:PrecompileBeforePublish=true
```

This would either precompile the .aspx file as well as copying the .zip file locally on the artifact staging directory on the agent machine. Use the `$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)` variable to refer to this directory in subsequent tasks in order to publish this artifact.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a try. I knew there could be a magic property to do this but I wasn't able to find it :-) I'm already generating the msdeploy package (.zip file) on other builds, I just needed a way to detect errors in the .aspx files at build time.

Comment: Thanks again Luca. I had to make some changes in order to make it work for me, check my answer.

Comment: @Rui can you share which kind of problem did you got with the proposed msbuild arguments? In your case you need to invoke msbuild twice, not once as here.

Comment: I was trying to invoke msbuild once, maybe that was my mistake. I don't remember exactly what were the errors. Also, I had to use the `OutputPath` parameter otherwise all assemblies etc would be generated on the `$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)` folder.

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned by Luca, `PrecompileBeforePublish` does the trick.

I decided to post another answer because the MSBuild arguments he gave as an example did not work for me. I used the following arguments:

```
/t:Package 
/p:PackageLocation="$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)\website.zip"     
/p:OutputPath=.\bin 
/p:Configuration=$(BuildConfiguration) 
/p:PrecompileBeforePublish=true
```

Build is now detecting errors in the .aspx pages such as missing resources:

[image]